# Double integral - don't know how to find the new interval

Tags: integration

I have this exercise. $D = \{(x,y) \mid x \leqslant x^2 + y^2 \leqslant 7x\}$ and I need to find the double integral of $f(x,y)$.

So, I understand from my $D$, that actually I have two circles with centers in $(1/2,0)$ and $(7/2,0)$, one in another.

I want to do intergration by the substitution: $x = r \cos(\theta), y = r \sin(\theta)$.

I don't understand how I find my new interval in that example. Can somebody explain it to me?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Can you also give us the function $f$, that might favor one parametrisation over another?

Comment: It will be easier if you use polar coordinates centered on those circles and then subtract the value of the integral over the small circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supopse $R_1$ and $R_2$ are the interiors of the bigger and smaller circles respectively. You need to calculate the integral over the grey region.

[image]

If $r,\theta$ are defined in the standard way and if a point with coordinates $(r,\theta)$ lies on a circle with radius $R$ and center $(R,0)$ we have

$${r\over \sin(\pi-2\theta)}={R\over \sin(\theta)}\Rightarrow r=2R\cos\theta$$

[image]

So if $\theta$ is fixed $r$ varies from $2\times0.5\cos\theta$ to $2\times3.5\cos\theta$  in the region of integration.

[image]

$$\iint_D f(x,y)dxdy=\iint_{R_1}f(x,y)dxdy-\iint_{R_2}f(x,y)dxdy=\\
\int_{-{\pi\over2}}^{{\pi\over2}}\int_{0}^{2\times3.5\cos\theta}f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)rdrd\theta-\int_{-{\pi\over2}}^{{\pi\over2}}\int_{0}^{2\times0.5\cos\theta}f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)rdrd\theta\\
=\int_{-{\pi\over2}}^{{\pi\over2}}\int_{2\times 0.5\cos\theta}^{2\times3.5\cos\theta}f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)rdrd\theta$$

Comment: That i understood. But the question is very specific, it looks like this: 

"The new interval where the integration will be done is:
            something<r<something
            something<O<something
"

Otherwise i would do the same as you proposed. But thats why i dont understand, why the question formulated like this, because there are two intervals of two diffrent integrals, that we are calculating. 
But in the question it asks me to write one interval of integration. 
Any idea ???

Comment: i mean one interval for r and one for theta as i wrote.

Comment: @user183297 edited. Is that what you want?

Comment: oh, of course ) Now i get it, thank you a lot.

Comment: exept that it says to me that the interval 0<t<2pi and 0.5<r<3.5 is wrong (it is a mathnet question, i have 4 attempts and it has automatic answer check). Very strange.

Comment: are you sure that its from 0.5 to 3.5? It seems to be right, but it isnt accepting this answer. And can you explain why it is from -pi/2 to +pi/2. I thought about it by intuition, but what is the equation ?

Comment: @user183297 I think it's correct now, let me add some explanation

Comment: @user183297 Is it ok now?

Comment: i will check later and tell you.

Comment: it is correct )